# Cannot call method 'path' of undefined when using Angular $location.path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've tried multiple solutions found on SO but I'm obviously missing something fundamental as no matter what I try I cannot get the particle view to change on submission of a form (or click of a button).

Here's the code:

```
propertyControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'SearchData', '$location', 
function($scope, SearchData, $routeParams, $location) {

    SearchData.set('postcode', $scope.postcode);
    SearchData.set('radius', $scope.radius);
    SearchData.set('minBeds', $scope.minBeds);
    SearchData.set('minPrice', $scope.minPrice);

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $location.path('/properties');
    }

}]);
```

And in the `home.html` partial

```
<input type="submit" class="topcoat-button--cta" value="Search">
```

My routing config

```
    var propertyApp = angular.module('propertyApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'propertyControllers'
]);

propertyApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        when('/properties', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/property-list.html',
            controller: 'PropertyListCtrl'
        }).
        when('/properties/:propertyId', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/property-detail.html',
            controller: 'PropertyDetailCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: 'home'
        });

    }]);
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? The docs seem overly complex and all the simple examples I've found do what I'm doing...

Comment: Get your `HomeCtrl` dependencies straight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters in string form and the actual parameters don't match:

```
controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'SearchData', '$location', 
                function($scope, SearchData, $routeParams, $location)
```

You forgot to add `'$routeParams'` in the array, before `'$location'`.

Comment: Wow, embarrassing! Can't believe I missed that!